# How does the Sort Function work and what its parameter denotes?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    sort(arr, arr + n);
 
    cout << "\nArray after sorting using "
            "default sort is : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
 
    return 0;
}
```

How the sort function works here? why the sort function just contains array name as 'arr' and not the index? What 'arr + n' doing?

Comment: Are you aware of array-to-pointer decaying?

Comment: @foragerDev `std`. The code in the question has every name in `std` pulled into the global namespace

Comment: Why not read the documentation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). IN less than 5 seconds, you will find **Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in non-descending order. The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.** From that, it is **obvious** that `arr` and `arr + n` specify the range to sort. Reading a few C++ books would be a good idea to have some basic knowledge.

Comment: This should be more clear: https://godbolt.org/z/PMKhcYP6v

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort if you look at the documentation of `std::sort` it takes two pointers, to define the range you want to sort. So the fact is arrays and pointers are interchangeable. `arr` is pointer to first index of memory you allocated in contiguous memory, and `arr + n` define the range from intiail position of arr to `n` offset.

Comment: Side notes: it is consider a bad practice to use `using namespace std;` or `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` (this is none standard header specific for gcc).

Comment: Wherever you learned `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, avoid that site like the plague.

Answer (score 5):

`std::sort` is a function template, it operates on anything that satisfies [*`RandomAccessIterator`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), which pointers do (being the archetypical iterator types). The two argument overload compares elements with `<`.

In an ordinary function call<sup>1</sup>, the name of an array is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element. This is called [*array to pointer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Array_to_pointer_conversion) decay. In particular, function templates will decay arrays to pointers when the type parameters are being determined.

`arr + n` calculates the pointer `n` elements into `arr`, which (in this case) is the special one-past-the-end element, which can be pointed to but not dereferenced. `std::sort(first, last)` on the half-open range [first, last).

1. Unless the function takes a reference-to-array parameter